# Recursion in function creating DOM tree

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

Good people, explain to me, please work this function:

```
function createTreeDom(obj) {
  if (isObjectEmpty(obj)) return;

  var ul = document.createElement('ul');

  for (var key in obj) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = key;

    var childrenUl = createTreeDom(obj[key]);
    if (childrenUl) li.appendChild(childrenUl);

    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  return ul;
}
```

Here's a link to the sandbox, it's full code: http://jsbin.com/zonoxereqa/1/edit

How do I behold these functions very well understood:

```
function isObjectEmpty(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function createTree(container, obj) {
  container.appendChild( createTreeDom(obj) );
}
```

Only `createTreeDom(obj)` of recursive functions I do not really understand her work, please, help me to explain her work.

I still do not understand what is assigned to the variable childrenUl? Why is it always in the debugger undefined?

Comment: @AlienWebguy, sorry, but I have a whole day trying to figure out this function, simply recursion loop knocks me up.

Comment: Hey, guys, I wouldn't be so quick to vote to close: the recursion might not be easy to understand here for someone. Aleksandr, I recommend to change the title to something more specific like *Recursion in function creating DOM tree*

Comment: If your question will be closed, I recommend to specify exactly which part you don't understand. And instead of *please help me* formulate some specific question using question mark: two guys voted "unclear what you are asking" just because they don't see the question mark.

Comment: Ok, now I'll know.

I painted a job this function like this: [screenshot of Sublime Text](http://savepic.su/4412659.png).

Comment: @JanTuroň, why childrenUl always undefined debugger?

Comment: childrenUl is undefined if and only if there is no sublist in the node: the `if (childrenUl)` stops the recursion then. When it is not empty, the recursion takes the non-empty object and creates the subtree by calling itself. If the object is empty, the `if (isObjectEmpty(obj)) return;` returns the undefined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates nested lists using nested objects. In one level nesting, it creates a single level simple `ul li, li ...` list. But if some value is non-empty object like this

```
var arg = { "one":{}, "two":{}, "three":{"subone":{}, "subtwo":{}}, "four":{}};
```

then the subobject is appended as the sublist in the recursion

```
var childrenUl = createTreeDom(obj[key]);
if (childrenUl) li.appendChild(childrenUl);
```

If the value is not empty object, no sublist is created, since there is a stop condition as the first command:

```
if (isObjectEmpty(obj)) return;
```

Step by step for the array above: for the first item, the function creates `ul` element and adds `li` into it, with the `key="one"` and `obj[key]={}`:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

But it is not done yet, now the recursion is called: `createTreeDom({})`. Since `isObjectEmpty({})` (obviously) returns true, the recursion ends and `childrenUl` is undefined. Therefore, no contents is added to `li` and the cycle jumps to the second node, which is also just a simple string literal, so it adds another `li` node:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Now the point: the third argument. Before the execution goes to the recursion, it looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

But the value of the third member is not an empty object, so the command

```
if (childrenUl) li.appendChild(childrenUl);
```

creates an `ul` node filled with its contents step by step like above and **appends it** to the `li` element:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three
    <ul>
      <li>subone</li>
      <li>subtwo</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If some of the nested item contained another non-empty object, it would be appended as sub-sub list to some sub-list `li` and so on.

There could be better to read equivalent:

```
function createTreeDom(obj) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');

  for (var key in obj) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = key;

    if (!isObjectEmpty(obj[key])) {
      var childrenUl = createTreeDom(obj[key]);
      li.appendChild(childrenUl);
    }

    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  return ul;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand that this function does, I just want to understand her work. I confusing recursion loop.

Comment: I also used the debugger, but not fully understood. But I'm still a beginner in programming. I would like that helped me understand.

Comment: I tried to explain it step by step. Is it clear now or is there still some tricky part?

Comment: Now it has become more clear, I will try again to see through the debugger, and I will read your response.

Comment: I also added the equivalent function which is simpler to understand at the end of my answer - try to figure out why those two product the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to understand. Now the situation with the cycle I became less clear.

Comment: For every iteration, the `key` is filled with the string literal and the value is `{}` (for non-nested list item) or non-empty object: in that case, the function calls itself with another argument. There must be some stop-condition to prevent infinite recursion, and that is the `if`.

Comment: Please see whether I described the work function. Here's a link to the sandbox: http://jsbin.com/sizobopofe/1/edit?js,output

Comment: More or less. The `return;` command actually returns undefined, which is falsy value. For every call it creates `li` for every key. If the value is non-empty object, it creates `ul` in that `li` (the sublist).

Comment: Well, in general, all right written?

Comment: Yes. Something is not technically accurate (false is not falsy, *condition does not work* is not *condition is not satisfied*), but in general, you get the idea.

Comment: I get it. When the condition is not triggered `if (isObjectEmpty (obj)) return;` and the function exits, it returns a variable childrenUl not false, and undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much. Without you, I would long to understand recursion.