# Add check boxes to table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to create dynamic tables and populate data using below code and its working fine, But I need to add a checkbox selection to each table row, I've tried few different ways but it's not working.

**Code**

```
//create dt by reading xml string
var xmlString = '<DataTables xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://C:/FRM/xsd/DataTables.xsd" ><Table name="dt_EdgeCaseHome"><Header><Column name="Username" type="String" /><Column name="Email" type="String" /><Column name="Password" type="String" /></Header><Row><Value>brian</Value><Value>brianf@edge.com</Value><Value>qwerty</Value></Row></Table><Table name="dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum"><Header><Column name="AppHeader" type="String" /><Column name="UserID" type="String" /><Column name="Service" type="String" /><Column name="Clients" type="String" /></Header><Row><Value>Contract</Value><Value>47</Value><Value>Agent</Value><Value>Exodus</Value></Row><Row><Value>Contract</Value><Value>49</Value><Value>Agent</Value><Value>Prometheus</Value></Row></Table></DataTables>',
xml,

// Create table element
table = document.createElement('table');
table.style.width = '100%';
table.setAttribute('border', '1');
tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
tr = tbdy.insertRow();
tr.id='header';
// Parse the xml
if (window.DOMParser){ // Standard browsers
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
}
else { // Internet Explorer
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(xmlString); 
}

var tables = xml.getElementsByTagName("Table");

// for each table
for(var t=0; t<tables.length; t++){
    tableName = tables[t].getAttribute("name");
  console.log(tableName);
  var dtName="dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum";
  if(dtName.match(tableName)){
  // for each table header
    var headers = tables[t].getElementsByTagName("Header");
    var cols = headers[0].childNodes;
    for(var c=0;c<cols.length;c++){
    columnName = cols[c].getAttribute("name");
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.id=c;
    td.setAttribute('name',columnName);
    td.textContent = columnName;
    console.log(columnName);
    }

    // for each table row
    var rows = tables[t].getElementsByTagName("Row");
    for(var r=0;r<rows.length;r++){
        console.log("row "+r);
      tr = tbdy.insertRow();
      tr.id='iteration_'+r;
        var vals = rows[r].childNodes;
        for(var x=0;x<vals.length;x++){
        value = vals[x].textContent;
      console.log(value);
      td = tr.insertCell();
      td.id=x;
      td.setAttribute('value', value)
      td.textContent = value;
      }
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(tbdy);
    // Append table to the body
    document.body.appendChild(table);
  }
}
```

Here is the demo

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Can someone help me on figuring this out? How can I modify the below code to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of table do you use? At least it seems yours is not a standard html table.

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "*I need...a checkbox selection*"? What *is* a "*checkbox selection*"? Where in the table do you want these checkboxes to be inserted? When they're changed (checked/unchecked) what do you want them to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
//create dt by reading xml string
var xmlString = '<DataTables xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file://C:/FRM/xsd/DataTables.xsd" ><Table name="dt_EdgeCaseHome"><Header><Column name="Username" type="String" /><Column name="Email" type="String" /><Column name="Password" type="String" /></Header><Row><Value>brian</Value><Value>brianf@edge.com</Value><Value>qwerty</Value></Row></Table><Table name="dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum"><Header><Column name="AppHeader" type="String" /><Column name="UserID" type="String" /><Column name="Service" type="String" /><Column name="Clients" type="String" /></Header><Row><Value>Contract</Value><Value>47</Value><Value>Agent</Value><Value>Exodus</Value></Row><Row><Value>Contract</Value><Value>49</Value><Value>Agent</Value><Value>Prometheus</Value></Row></Table></DataTables>',
xml,

// Create table element
table = document.createElement('table');
table.style.width = '100%';
table.setAttribute('border', '1');
tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
tr = tbdy.insertRow();
tr.id='header';
// Parse the xml
if (window.DOMParser){ // Standard browsers
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
}
else { // Internet Explorer
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(xmlString); 
}

var tables = xml.getElementsByTagName("Table");

// for each table
for(var t=0; t<tables.length; t++){
    tableName = tables[t].getAttribute("name");
  console.log(tableName);
  var dtName="dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum";
  if(dtName.match(tableName)){
  // for each table header
    var headers = tables[t].getElementsByTagName("Header");
    var cols = headers[0].childNodes;
    for(var c=0;c<cols.length;c++){
    columnName = cols[c].getAttribute("name");
    td = tr.insertCell();
    td.id=c;
    td.setAttribute('name',columnName);
    td.textContent = columnName;
    console.log(columnName);
    }
    var th = tr.insertCell();
    th.id = 'selection';
    th.textContent = 'Select';

    // for each table row
    var rows = tables[t].getElementsByTagName("Row");
    for(var r=0;r<rows.length;r++){
        console.log("row "+r);
      tr = tbdy.insertRow();
      tr.id='iteration_'+r;
        var vals = rows[r].childNodes;
        for(var x=0;x<vals.length;x++){
        value = vals[x].textContent;
        console.log(value);
        td = tr.insertCell();
        td.id=x;
        td.setAttribute('value', value)
        td.textContent = value;
      }
      var select = tr.insertCell();
      var checkbox =  document.createElement("input");
      checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
      checkbox.setAttribute('name', tr.id);
      select.appendChild(checkbox);
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(tbdy);
    // Append table to the body
    document.body.appendChild(table);
  }
}
```

Create the checkbox elements in another column. Assign the row id as the name so that value can be passed to other scripts.

Comment: yes this does add the checkbox (s) to each row, but I need to add it to the column header row as well and when clicked on that check box it should act as a select all / deselect all  for all below check boxes.

Comment: Ok well you didn't mention that new problem in your question :)

Comment: yes, it was on my mind and I thought I wrote it. please do provide a solution for that as well, appreciate your support

Comment: SO is not a free coding service it is for helping you to learn how to do it yourself. Think through what it is you need to do:

1. Add a checkbox to the header row for Select All.
2. Attach a change or click event to the Select All checkbox
3. On change or click, get all the other checkboxes
4. For loop through them to make them checked or unchecked depending on the state of the Select All checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

This code is a bit hard to read. Hopefully I understand what you want to achieve.

You need to add an extra item to the array. Can be done by using:

`vals = [{'textContent': 'generic checkbox item?'}, ...vals];`

Right after the line:
`var vals = rows[r].childNodes;`

*Optional:
May I suggest using a recursive function for building dom elements? Multiple for-loops are not really something I would suggest. Especially if the number of iterations goes beyond 2 rows.*

Comment: Please do help me on building that recursive function, I'm open to better alternatives if there is any

Comment: Please look at this page, I hope it helps. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940845/recursion-in-function-creating-dom-tree)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply add cb by this code:

```
  td = tr.insertCell();
  var newCheckBox = document.createElement('input');
  newCheckBox .type = 'checkbox';
  newCheckBox .setAttribute('id', 'cb_test' + r);
  td.appendChild(newCheckBox );
```